# XSLT Transform use attribute as input to change sibling attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a quite flat XML file for which I want to change some attributes, depending on an input list of some kind. The tricky part which I'm not able to solve is that I also want to change the attribute not only on one node but also on a sibling node that references the found node.

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <SubItem id="id21" cls="classA" name="FirstSub" master="#id30"/>
    <SubItem id="id22" cls="classA" name="SecondSub" master="#id31"/>
    <SubItem id="id23" cls="classA" name="ThirdSub" master="#id32"/>
    <SubItem id="id24" cls="classA" name="FourthSub" master="#id33"/>
    <SubItem id="id25" cls="classA" name="FifthSub" master="#id34"/>
    <Item id="id30" cls="classA" name="First"/>
    <Item id="id31" cls="classA" name="Second"/>
    <Item id="id32" cls="classA" name="Third"/>
    <Item id="id33" cls="classA" name="Fourth"/>
    <Item id="id34" cls="classA" name="Fifth" />
</Root>
```

And the following additional input file listing the `name` values of elements where I want to change the `cls` attribute value:

```
<input>
    <ToClassB>
        <Name>Second</Name>
        <Name>Third</Name>
    </ToClassB>
</input>
```

And the following XSLT, which works fine for elements with `name` values matching those in the additional input list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:plm="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:variable name="inputs" select="document('file:/C:/Temp//demoInput.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root/Item/@name[. = $inputs/input/ToClassB/Name/text()]">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="../@id"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../@name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="cls">
            <xsl:value-of select="'classB'" />
        </xsl:attribute>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <SubItem id="id21" cls="classA" name="FirstSub" master="#id30"/>
    <SubItem id="id22" cls="ClassB" name="SecondSub" master="#id31"/>
    <SubItem id="id23" cls="ClassB" name="ThirdSub" master="#id32"/>
    <SubItem id="id24" cls="classA" name="FourthSub" master="#id33"/>
    <SubItem id="id25" cls="classA" name="FifthSub" master="#id34"/>
    <Item id="id30" cls="classA" name="First"/>
    <Item id="id31" cls="ClassB" name="Second"/>
    <Item id="id32" cls="ClassB" name="Third"/>
    <Item id="id33" cls="classA" name="Fourth"/>
    <Item id="id34" cls="classA" name="Fifth"/>
</Root>
```

Item tags with `name` values of `"Second"` or `"Third"` are matched, and their `cls` attribute values are changed to `ClassB`, as well as the `cls` attribute values for related `SubItem` elements (master attribute referencing id attribute on `Item` elements).

Is this possible at all with XSLT or do I need to use some programming?

Comment: Can you rely on every `<SubItem>` being associated with an `<Item>` in the same document, via `SubItem/@master` and `Item/@id`?  Also, do you need to preserve the element order?

Comment: The point of my line of questioning is that you can conceivably restructure your stylesheet so that the template the template for `<Root>` does not directly apply templates to the `<SubItem>` children, but instead relies on the template(s) for `<Item>` to apply templates to the associated `<SubItem>`s.  You'll then have enough context to correctly direct how their `cls` attributes should be transformed.

Comment: XSLT _is_ programming ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an xsl:key to reference the `Item` from the `SubItem`. You could use a single template and use either the `id` or `master` attributes to access the key.

Example...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="itemsByID" match="Item" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:variable name="inputs" 
    select="document('demoInput.xml')/input/ToClassB/Name"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item|SubItem">
    <xsl:variable name="refid" 
      select="if (@master) then substring-after(@master,'#') else @id"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="cls" 
        select="if (key('itemsByID',$refid)/@name = $inputs) 
        then 'ClassB' else @cls"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Root>
   <SubItem id="id21" cls="classA" name="FirstSub" master="#id30"/>
   <SubItem id="id22" cls="ClassB" name="SecondSub" master="#id31"/>
   <SubItem id="id23" cls="ClassB" name="ThirdSub" master="#id32"/>
   <SubItem id="id24" cls="classA" name="FourthSub" master="#id33"/>
   <SubItem id="id25" cls="classA" name="FifthSub" master="#id34"/>
   <Item id="id30" cls="classA" name="First"/>
   <Item id="id31" cls="ClassB" name="Second"/>
   <Item id="id32" cls="ClassB" name="Third"/>
   <Item id="id33" cls="classA" name="Fourth"/>
   <Item id="id34" cls="classA" name="Fifth"/>
</Root>
```